# Why is that not all objects are printed when I print session objects?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am working on `sqlalchemy` in `python`. I have defined four objects for a table(users) in database using `mapper`. Say these objects are `a,b,c,d`. I have added them to `session`. Then I made a query for whose user name is `a`(It's object a). Then I have used `for` loop as below

```
Sessionclass = session_maker()
session = Sessionclass()   
session.add_all([a,b,c,d])
res = session.query(User).filter_by(username='a').first()
for obj in session:
    print(obj)
```

I got the output as object 'a'. Why are the other objs not printed?

Comment: I think it should be "for obj in res" . Furthermore, in "session.query(User).filter_by(username='a').first()" first() limits to one entry.

Comment: No. Its for obj in session:  I want the objects in session. I used query here to flush data into db. No special purpose for res.

Comment: Why not use `session.flush()` for flushing? Also, cannot reproduce. All objects printed correctly. How are a, b, c, and d defined?

Comment: Yeah! They are defined correctly. Because the code is too long I minimized it. And also you can flush using session.flush but I dont know if using query has effect on the code so I used query to flush in the code

Answer (score 0):

Basically as I understand, you are trying to display all the objects present in the `session` regardless of the below query you specified.

```
res = session.query(User).filter_by(username='a').first()
```

So in the `for` loop only providing the `session` directly won't let it iterate over, we have to query the table(`user`) present in the `session`.

```
Sessionclass = session_maker()
session = Sessionclass()   
session.add_all([a,b,c,d])
for obj in session.query(User):
    print(obj)
```

Comment: Thanks Faruk13. But can you mention the reason for above code? Basically if I comment query line and print objs from session, all of them will be printed. But after query, 'session' only allows to print objs in 'res'

Comment: If you want to iterate over `res` it will display all the objects that matches your query ie where `username` is `a`.